# Regex expression for grabbing certain keyword and combine them together

Tags: regex

I have the following text and i would like to grab the keyword "ATTEMPT TO ACCESS DATABASE" and "was denied", and combine these two together. However, there are some user and path name information in between these two keywords, and this makes it difficult for me to capture the thing i want, as i'm still not yet a regex expert. XD

> <182>Mar 27 09:38:55 4.3.2.1 [5439570:00311-46004] 03/11/2015 14:13:05
>   ATTEMPT TO ACCESS DATABASE mail/abc.nsf by USER was denied

Is there a single regex expression that can help me to fulfill my requirement? Would greatly appreciate for all the help!

Comment: A single regexp can only match one substring. To match multiple substrings you have to use capture groups and then append them in the result.

Comment: or is there any way i can ignore the words in between the "DATABASE" and "was denied"?

Comment: No. A regular expression always matches a contiguous part of the input. This is what capture groups are for, they allow you to retrieve parts of the matched string and use them.

Comment: Why do you need to combine them? Both "ATTEMPT TO ACCESS DATABASE" and "was denied" are a constant expressions - if you need to output them in a message, hard code it all. Just use `ATTEMPT TO ACCESS DATABASE.*was denied` to match every line with this error

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/eY7yE7/2):

`(ATTEMPT\s+TO\s+ACCESS\s+DATABASE\s+)(\S+)\s+by\s+([\w.-]+)\s+(was\s+denied)`

Ouput is:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [71-98] `ATTEMPT TO ACCESS DATABASE `
2.  [98-110]    `mail/abc.nsf`
3.  [114-118]   `USER`
4.  [119-129]   `was denied`
```

So, you can combine Group 1 and 4 to get `ATTEMPT TO ACCESS DATABASE was denied` (in any case due to `i` option), and Group 2 will contain the path name, and Group 3 will hold the user name.

Comment: Where did you see that `(\w+\/\w+\.\w+)` is enough to match database name? Why do you use 4 groups?

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE: Thank you for your remark. I updated it to `(\S+)`. 4 groups are used to get all the substrings mentioned in OP.